# How do I use a command block to summon a lightning bolt

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I use the command block to summon a lightning bolt in Minecraft pocket edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to DigMinecraft, it is very simple to summon a lightning bolt and is supported on all pocket editions version 0.16.0 or higher:

```
/summon lightning_bolt
```

If you want to know how to control the lightning bolt and its coordinates, visit [this DigMinecraft page](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/summon_lightning_bolt.php)

Comment: ...or just the wiki.

Comment: @Fabian Ya, I could say that, but I'd like to give credit to the wiki by at least mentioning it's name.

Comment: I believe he meant the official wiki.  [Here is the official wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#summon) on the summon command, which includes an example that summons a lightning bolt.